# How do I untar multiple files within each tar files, exclusively in the Linux shell?

Tags: shellcode

I'm trying to untar a tarball of files and the shellcode will not work properly, the directory of the tarball is /problems/like1000_0_369bbdba2af17750ddf10cc415672f1c and my user is publicVoid@pico-2019-shell1: . There are about 1000 tar files and I need to get to the last one, any help would be appreciated as I am a beginner in this.

```
#! /bin/sh

for f in 1000.tar
do
  tar xf "$f" -C publicVoid@pico-2019-shell1:/problems/like1000_0_369bbdba2af17750ddf10cc415672f1c
done
```

This is the error

```
publicVoid@pico-2019-shell1:~/bin$ ./tarScrip
tar: 1000.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
publicVoid@pico-2019-shell1:~/bin$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing too but it seems like you cant. the best bet is to try and untar it using a program that will allow it to. the tr file is a file containing may backups so there is a chance that the 1000 tar might cause a lot of lag due to the size. I am a beginner at shellcode but I have been somewhat successful at the shell. I do this for fun but I wish you good luck and may u win the cash